# Play/Pause status in Adobe Captivate

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-captivate

I'm new to Captivate software and looking for some help with it.
What am I doing is Play/Pause widget in Flash and everything works fine until there is `Pause After time` setting on buttons or slides pause at the end of them. I spent lots of time trying to find out how to receive notification about changing play/pause status of the captivate course. Now I'm checking this status with

```
playing = m_VariableHandle.rdcmndPause == 0;
//m_VariableHandle is movieHandle.getMovieProps().variablesHandle
```

code, but it only works if user clicks on playbar buttons or on my own button. But if slide pauses at the end or some button causes it to stop, then `rdcmndPause` is still 0.

So is there any way to check if movie is playing at any point of time? Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after two more hours of digging I've found what I was looking for, I think. At least I've found a workaround and it works.

In my widget I'm listening to `enterFrame` event and checking if `rdinfoCurrentFrame` property in `variablesHandle` is changed. If not the movie is paused. That's it.

```
if (m_VariableHandle)
{
    playing = m_VariableHandle.rdcmndPause == 0;
    if (playing && pFrame == m_VariableHandle.rdinfoCurrentFrame)
        playing = false;
    pFrame = m_VariableHandle.rdinfoCurrentFrame;
}
```